# copying the Data to the next available Row in Another Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have run into a small issue with this script, it does copy the values in the range but pastes them under the 1500 cell in column A on the destination Sheet. I can't seem to get it to paste to the next free cell in Col A.

```
function EndShift() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var source = ss.getSheetByName('Logbook');
  var dataToCopy = source.getRange('A7:F40');
  var dataToClear = source.getRange('C7:F40');
  var copyToSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Log Sheet');
  var sourceValues = dataToCopy.getValues();
  var lastRowUsed = copyToSheet.getRange(1,1);
  var lastRow = lastRowUsed.getLastRow();

  copyToSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, sourceValues.length, 6).setValues(sourceValues);


  dataToClear.clear({contentsOnly:true});

};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that you spreadsheet has formulas that are returning an empty text or something similar. Review your spreadsheet carefully and adjust the formulas accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

```
unction EndShift() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var source = ss.getSheetByName('Logbook');
  var dataToCopy = source.getRange('A7:F40');
  var dataToClear = source.getRange('C7:F40');
  var copyToSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Log Sheet');
  var sourceValues = dataToCopy.getValues();
  var lastRowUsed = copyToSheet.getRange(1,1);
  var lastRow = lastRowUsed.getLastRow();

  copyToSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, sourceValues.length, 6).setValues(sourceValues);


  dataToClear.clear({contentsOnly:true});

};
```